# How to edit cells in a Pandas DataFrame without header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame without header and I need to edit all cells.

Cells are composed by a product name and a certain number, for example:

```
'Pasta=3'
```

Example:

```
      0           1               2              3    
0  'Pasta=3'   'Soup=2'       'Potatoes=4'     None
1  'Cheese=1'  'Milk=2'        None            None
2  'Eggs=6'    'Cleaners=1'   'Beef=2'        'Fish=1'
3  'Apples=3'  'Banana=2'     'Pear=4'         None
```

Now I have to remove the equality symbol and the number. So, if I have

```
'Pasta=3'
```

I have to remove '=3' to obtain

```
'Pasta'
```

How can I do it, if the dataframe hasn't header?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, they have a "header" (i.e. column name). In your case, it is either `0` or `"0"` (integer 0, or string 0). So you can still access the columns by `df[0]` or `df["0"]` depending on whether that's a integer or string.

Second, to remove everything after the `=`, just use `df.replace` on every column by stating `regex=True`

```
df.replace(r'=.*','', regex=True)
```

You can also use `apply` (slower, prefer the first method)

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(r'=.*',''))
```